# WIX: do I have to manually recreate all elements of a dialog, including banners and buttons?

Tags: wix

New to WIX here :-)

I added a new dialog to my WIX setup project, and it works well, except that this dialog ONLY shows the controls I added to it - it doesn't have the next/back/cancel buttons or the banner that the other dialogs have.

Did I do something wrong or do I have to manually recreate all controls, inclulding banners? If I have to manually recreate them, where do I find the WXS files that contains the originals?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <RadioButtonGroup Property="MyApp_Database_Type">
        <RadioButton Height="17" Text="Dedicated" Value="Dedicated" Width="348" X="0"
                     Y="0" />
        <RadioButton Height="17" Text="Shared" Value="Shared" Width="348" X="0"
                     Y="18" />
        <RadioButton Height="17" Text="Single User" Value="Single User" Width="348" X="0"
                     Y="36" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
      <Dialog Id="MyApp_UI_DatabaseProperties" X="50" Y="50" Width="373" Height="287"
              Title="[ProductName]: Database Properties">
        <Control Id="CTL_MyApp_UI_DatabaseProperties" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="18" Y="108" Width="348" Height="48"
                 Property="MyApp_Database_Type" Text="System Type" TabSkip="no" />

        <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243"
                 Width="56" Height="17" Hidden="no" Disabled="no" Text="Back" />

        <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton"
                 X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes"
                 Text="Next" Hidden="no" Disabled="no">
        </Control>
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to fully define the dialog you want to use. Each dialog is a self contained and describing thing. It doesn't know about the layout or format of any other dialogs in the installation.

You can see examples of the dialogs you are probably using with the WixUIExtension.dll right [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib). This is the source code of the UIExtension's wixlib.

You should be able to simply copy over the shared components from the other dialogs into the one you are describing to get it working as you expect.